# Responsive css for mobile and desktop is interrupting

Tags: html, css

When I write css for 320px ( mobile phone ) it was worked well, but problem is when I resize my screen from 320px to 1366px then that css which is wrote for 320px still work on 1366px and got high priority.

Screenshot added for better explain.

[image]

look at red mark in the screenshot. How will I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used "min-width".That's why it is creating problem.
use @media screen and (max-width: 320px;)
It will work